# Uptime and rank

Tags: php, mysql

**1.** I have a website of servers list and I want to calculate uptime based online and offline activity. 
I have two columns in database: **online_time** and **offline_time**. I want to scan servers every 5 minutes with a cron job and when the server is online or offline, I will add +1 to online or offline columns.
What is the best practice to calculate uptime of this two values and also what is the best practice to get uptime in this case?

**2.** On this above example, I want to set a rank for all servers from database based on number of votes. Is ok to create a **rank** column, and select all servers based on below query and to update **rank** column with rank number from below query for every server and when I want to search a server, to appear rank in table of html?

```
SELECT    id,votes,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      servers p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  votes DESC;
```

Comment: Best practice would be to have reliable servers that don't need babysitting...

Comment: Yes but the owner games love this...